# adafruit_requests Error: x509-crt-bundle:Failed to verify certificate

Tags: x509certificate, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm trying to get data from a weather API on a Raspberry Pi Pico running CircuitPython. It works on [this API](http://worldtimeapi.org/api/Europe/Berlin). Code:

```
pool = socketpool.SocketPool(wifi.radio)
requests = adafruit_requests.Session(pool, ssl.create_default_context())
url = "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=?????????????????????????&q=Berlin"
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)
print(data["temp_c"])
```

Error:

```
x509-crt-bundle:Failed to verify certificate
Backtracking (most recent request last):
  File "adafruit_requests.py", line 515, in _get_socket
OSError: (-12288, 'MBEDTLS_ERR_X509_FATAL_ERROR')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Backtracking (most recent request last):
  File "<stdin>", line 139, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 95, in getWeather
  File "adafruit_requests.py", line 711, in get
  File "adafruit_requests.py", line 650, in request
  File "adafruit_requests.py", line 496, in _get_socket
RuntimeError: Sending request failed
```

Comment: Your 'works' case is not https so it does not even try to use any certificate. Did or can you try `HTTPS://worldtimeapi.org` -- which uses a LetsEncrypt cert similar to that for `api.weatherapi.com` ? How about non-LE sites like `https://www.google.com https://www.bing.com https://www.amazon.com` ?

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. This error means that 1) the service you are connecting to is not configured correctly 2) your local clock is very out of sync 3) Your client cannot negotiate the protocol / cipher or 4) you don't have a local version of the CA cert to validate against.